# date_facet in Django Haystack not faceting by date

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I'm using Haystack 2.8.1 with Django 2.1 and Solr 6.6.6.

I have no problems using facets, however date faceting is not working.

My index:

```
class ConflitoIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    data_inicio = indexes.DateField(model_attr="data_inicio", faceted=True, null=True)

    def get_model(self):
        return Conflito

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        return self.get_model().objects.all()
```

The following script on shell:

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet                                                                                                   
import datetime                                                                                                                             
sqs = SearchQuerySet().date_facet("data_inicio", start_date=datetime.date(1980, 1, 1), end_date=datetime.date(2019, 1, 1), gap_by="year")
```

results in:

```
In [1]: sqs.facet_counts()                                                                                                                          
Out[1]: {'fields': {}, 'dates': {}, 'queries': {}}
```

However, the following script results in:

```
In [1]: from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet                                                                                                   
In [2]: import datetime                                                                                                                             
In [3]: sqs = SearchQuerySet().facet('data_inicio')                                                                                                 
In [4]: sqs.facet_counts()                                                                                                                          
Out[4]: 
{'fields': {'data_inicio': [('1500-01-01T00:00:00Z', 212),
   ('1986-12-29T00:00:00Z', 148),
   ('2010-01-01T00:00:00Z', 141),
   ('1979-12-29T00:00:00Z', 130),
   ('2018-01-01T00:00:00Z', 104),
   ('1984-12-29T00:00:00Z', 100),
   ...
   ('2013-10-16T00:00:00Z', 17),
   ('1982-12-02T00:00:00Z', 16),
   ('1988-02-28T00:00:00Z', 16),
   ('1996-05-29T00:00:00Z', 16),
   ('1998-03-29T00:00:00Z', 16),
   ('2000-01-31T00:00:00Z', 16)]},
 'dates': {},
 'queries': {}}
```

Thus, faceting is not working for dates. What can be wrong in my code? Unfortunately there are very few examples for date faceting in Haystack documentation.

best,
alan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occour because facet.date API is gone in Solr 6.6, replaced with facet.range. More details found in [Solr doc](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/working-with-dates.html) and [issue #1572](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/issues/1572)

To solved consider [PR #1690](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack/pull/1690) with:

- fixed backend
- add attribute `date_facet_fields` on generic_views receiving a list of date_facet kwargs. Ex.:

```py
# your views.py
import datetime
...
class YourFacetedSearchView(FacetedSearchView):
    date_facet_fields = [
        {'field': 'data_inicio',
         'start_date': datetime.date(1980, 1, 1),
         'end_date': datetime.date.today(),
         'gap_by': 'year'},
    ]

    facet_fields = [...]
...
```

best regards,

Fábio